# How to convert image (byte) to Base64 (str) Odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

i can't find a way to convert the image_1920 field to a string (base64), someone knows how to do it I would appreciate your help

I've done this but it doesn't convert it to str

```
base64.b64encode(record.image_1920)
```

The field is of this type!

[image]

Note: Odoo14 Community

ir_attachment
[image]

How do I get the base64?

Comment: As i can see record.image_1920 is bytestring b'61.31Kb'
Looks like you expect image in this field, but it is not.

Comment: thanks, I'm a bit new to Odoo, I checked and the images I see that they are saved in ir_attachment, how can I bring that image as base64, update my question with the ir.attachment object

Answer (score 1):

what I did is bring the record `ir.attachment`, then I get the absolute path of the image file and that's it!

```
att = self.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().search([('id', '=', res[0])])
valores = self.env['ir.attachment'].sudo()._get_datas_related_values(att.datas,
                                                                         att.mimetype)
dir = self.env['ir.attachment']._full_path(valores['store_fname'])
with open(dir, "rb") as image_file:
        data = image_file.read()
        decode = data.decode("utf-8")
        return decode #base64 file
```

Comment: Ah, smart solution. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

The `record.image_1920` is already Base64 encoded and you have to *decode* it. So try `base64.b64decode(record.image_1920)` instead of `base64.b64encode(record.image_1920)`.

Comment: not work!!! the console throws: `{Error}Incorrect padding`